# Cannot move Controller of <A-frame> up and down normally on mobile

Tags: javascript

Only on mobile browser I can't move the camera up and down:

```
<body>
    <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
        <a-sky src="./assets/7.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0" radius="500"></a-sky>
        <a-entity camera look-controls orbit-controls="target: 0 1.6 -0.5; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 180; initialPosition: 0 5 15"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get it,is not supported in a-frame